# Which semaphore type should I use for client-side HttpWebRequest throttling?

Tags: .net, multithreading, http

#### Background

I have a windows service calls a REST web service using `HttpWebRequest`, I'm using a `BlockingCollection<T>` to implement a Producer/Consumer pattern.  Every so often, my web service returns `502 Bad Gateway` or `503 Service Unavailable`.

I'm 95% certain the web service is just getting flooded.  So I'd like to throttle the requests on the client side whenever I get one of these responses.

#### Question

Which type of semaphore should I use? .Net 4/4.5 types are ok.  Here's the psuedocode for my proposed solution, the consumers are run in parallel:

```cs
class Worker {
    Semaphore _cooldown = new Semaphore();

    void Run() {
        StartProducersInParallel();
        StartConsumersInParallel();
    }
    
    void Produce() {...}
    void Consume() {
        _cooldown.Wait(1000);
        try {
            var response = proxy.GetResponse();
        } catch (ex) {
            if (ex.Status == 502 || ex.Status == 503) {
                _cooldown.Signal();
                // ... wait here and then retry once
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear why you are contemplating a synchronization object.  You slow code down with Thread.Sleep(), a bool is good enough to flag the condition.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm running the consumers in parallel. I considered adding a Thread.Sleep(), but the problem is intermittent.  That solution would arbitrarily slow down the windows service even when the server was under no load.

Comment: You can slow down multiple threads with ManualResetEvent.WaitOne(1000).  Call its Reset() method when you get the error return, Set() to let every run normal again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hans Passant's comment led me to this solution:

```
class Worker {
    ManualResetEventSlim _cooldown = new ManualResetEventSlim();

    void Run() {
        StartProducersInParallel();
        StartConsumersInParallel();
    }

    void Produce() {...}
    void Consume() {
        _cooldown.Wait(1000);
        var response;
        try {
            response = proxy.GetResponse();
            _cooldown.Set();
        } catch (ex) {
            if (ex.Status == 502 || ex.Status == 503) {
                _cooldown.Reset();
            } else {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you have Consumer/Producer you should be using the ReaderWriterLockSlim class, not Semaphore.
Represents a lock that is used to manage access to a resource, allowing multiple threads for reading or exclusive access for writing.

Comment: I don't ever write to the web service.  I'm trying to keep all of the consumer threads from making WebRequests when the web service is overloaded.